# MySQL Query to check a DateTime column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 application that is using a mysql db. Part of the functionality is that I am trying to query a table in my DB for all records where:

```
updated_at + 1.year <= DateTime.now
```

But I am having issues writing the query that would give me the expected results. Any ideas how I can go about doing this?

Comment: You are doing a mySql query or an active record query?

Comment: Beyond just the syntax... for best query performance, you'll want the SQL text that's submitted to the database to be of the form **`column<=const-const`**, rather than **`column+const<=const`**. (With the latter form, the expression on the left side of the comparison will need to be evaluated for *every* row in the table; with a bare column on the left side, MySQL can use a range scan operation on a suitable index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try date function:

```
updated_at + interval 1 year <= now()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
where('updated_at <= ?', 1.year.ago)`
```

because it is easier to understand.